# Swift. Set specific time format(12/24h) for custom Locale

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, nslocale

I want to get the time in 12h or 24h format from DateFormatter according to option "24-Hour-Time" in User Preferences.

If I set "24-Hour-Time" = "on" and DateFormatter like this:

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    print(locale)                            // "en_US (fixed)\n"
    formatter.locale = locale 
    formatter.dateStyle = .none
    formatter.timeStyle = .short

    formatter.string(from: Date()) // "2:54 PM" (not "14:54")
```

But if I set:

```
    let locale = Locale.current   // "en_US (current)\n"
```

instead of

```
    let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US") // "en_US (fixed)\n"
```

the result will be

```
formatter.string(from: Date()) // "14:54"
```

How to create custom locale setting 12 or 24 hour format.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve but you can check the user's 24h setting and set a custom dateFormat based on it. `extension DateFormatter { var is24h: Bool { return DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "j", options: 0, locale: .current)?.contains("a") == false } }`

Answer (score -1):

//MARK:- use this to convert 24 hours time format to 12 hour Formate String

```
 func TwelveHourFormateFrom24Hours(time : String)->String
    {
        let Time = time.components(separatedBy: ".")
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "H:mm:ss"

        if let inDate = dateFormatter.date(from: Time[0])
        {
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
            let outTime = dateFormatter.string(from: inDate)
            print("in \(time)")
            print("out \(outTime)")
            return outTime
        }
        return time
    }
```

//MARK:- 24 hour Formate String

```
 func TwentyFourHourFormate(time : String)->String
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"

        if let inDate = dateFormatter.date(from: time)
        {
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "H:mm:ss.sss"
            let outTime = dateFormatter.string(from: inDate)
            print("in \(time)")
            print("out \(outTime)")
            return outTime
        }
        return time
    }
```

Comment: It's not a question about converting dates between formats

Comment: it's also work for Date please my code and understand . i have convert string to date ,so you use direct Date instead of string.